# After Upgrade to magento2.4.2-p1 getting admin login error, redirecting to denied controller

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.1, magento2.4.2, magento2.4.0

I have upgraded to Magento2.4.2-p1, and I am not able to log in to admin. It is redirecting to the denied controller.
Check screenshot
[image]

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html
you need some suitable conditions for the upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling 2FA:

```
bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth
bin/magento cache:flush
```

From 2.4, 2FA is required for Admin login:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/security/two-factor-authentication.html

You might have some other issues because it doesnt look like you are loading in Javascript / CSS / HTML.

Comment: That I have already done.
but in magento2.4.2-p1 this is the issue if you disable 2FA from the config still it would not be disabled.
Check this file Magento\TwoFactorAuth\Model\Tfa.php

and check the function below. it is not picking up the value from config. Default it is setting as true
public function isEnabled()
{
return true;
}

Comment: @KamalMittal I updated my answer - you need to disable it and then flush the config.

Comment: performed the steps but no luck

Comment: @KamalMittal there is definitely something else happening here. Have you tried removing cookies from browser and visiting the admin page? (without pressing reload page, but just going to admin URL in another tab)

Comment: There is some stuff happening with /pub folder in 2.4.2 release. I think they moved index.php into /pub folder and that requires some adjustments in nginx.conf or apache2 setup. Please see Release Notes: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/open-source-2-4-2.html

Comment: If you are upgrading on a production site, I would roll it back. I'm in process of upgrading 2.3.3 to 2.4.2-p1 myself and I'm about 9 days into the bug fixes and tweaks. There are a lot of changes that happened from 2.3 to 2.4 versions. I would recommend fixing all the issues on DEV environment first and then moving those to the Production environment.

Comment: I think its somewhere here that talks about the /pub folder change: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html

Comment: yes, actually that's the same thing I am doing. I am upgrading it on my local system first then I will move it on prod.

Comment: It could be something in your NGINX setup. 2.4 upgrade required me to copy contents of nginx.conf.sample (was upgraded during the process) to nginx.conf in the main Magento folder. It should pull in all the changes required for the index.php inside /pub folder.